# mysql slow query with a list of id

Tags: java, mysql

I have a mysql table like:

```
create table table (
    id bigint auto_increment
    s_id varchar(30),
    col1 varchar(50),
    col2 varchar(50),
    col3 varchar(30),
    col4 varchar(30),
    col5 int,
    primary key(id),
    index idx_search(col1, col2, col3)
)
```

The table have more than 90 million rows of data. In the previous query, I get top 100 s_id. Now, I have a query to get the info of the s_id:

```
select s_id, col1, col2, col3, col4, max(col5) from table where col1 = 'XXX' and col2 = 'XXX' and s_id in (?, ?, ?, ...) group by s_id
```

This query speed is unstable, range 100ms to 4000ms.

When the `col1='full'` and `col2='full'`, it has more than 10 million rows of data in MySQL.

I also tried to add index like `idx_sid(s_id, col1, col2)`, it's helpless.

How can I speed up this query? Or any other solution?

Comment: What is '9kw' and '1kw' (it can't be 9 kilowatt / 1 kilowatt)?

Comment: Hello there.   We are missing some useful info.  What types of data fields are col1/col2/col3/col4?  Is s_id a bigint field?  These conditions can have major impacts on your query, especially when using the "in (?, ?...)" refinement.

Comment: sorry, I saw the comments and updated some of my descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

The sql indexes work when their order is from left to right. Because you have created your index to be (s_id,col1,col2), so your `WHERE` clause should contain these columns in the defined order itself. Using below query definitely speeds up your response time.

`select s_id, col1, col2, col3, col4 from table where s_id in (?, ?, ?, ...) and col1 = 'XXX' and col2 = 'XXX'`